# WinApi Window Creation

Tags: c#, winapi

Edit 1: Improved error checking, still not clear if there still exists a hidden error.

I've been attempting to create a custom window using P/Invoke calls to user32.dll from C#. My problem, however, is that with the minimal level of error reporting, I cannot determine the exact problem. I am fairly certain the problem stems from my definition or instantiation of WNDCLASSEX, since replacing the custom class with a system one such as "MDIClient" resolves the errors.

The primary file:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace CoreLib
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Basic window class.
    /// </summary>
    public class Window
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks for an error and reports it and it's location.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="location"></param>
        private static void checkError(string location)
        {
            int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if(error != 0)//if not NO_ERROR
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(location + " " + new Win32Exception(error).Message + " " + error);
            }
        }

        //various constants
        private const int CS_HREDRAW = 0x0002;
        private const int CS_VREDRAW = 0x0001;
        private const uint WS_OVERLAPPED = 0x0;
        private const uint WS_CAPTION = 0xC00000;
        private const uint WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000;
        private const uint WS_SIZEFRAME = 0x40000;
        private const uint WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x20000;
        private const uint WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x10000;
        private const uint WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_SIZEFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;
        private const int WINDOW_SHOW_NORMAL = 1;

        //the static hinstance
        private static IntPtr hInstance = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(typeof(Window).Module);//System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
        //the pointer to the window object
        private IntPtr windowPointer;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new Window with the given title.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="title"></param>
        public Window(string title)
        {
            //create a class for the window
            WNDCLASSEX clazz = new WNDCLASSEX();
            //initialize the class
            clazz.init(title, null);

            //register
            ushort atom = RegisterClassEx(ref clazz);
            if(atom == 0) checkError("RegisterClassEx");

            //create window
            windowPointer = CreateWindowEx(0, (uint)atom, title, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 200, 200, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, hInstance, IntPtr.Zero);
            if(windowPointer == IntPtr.Zero) checkError("CreateWindowEx");
            //show window
            ShowWindow(windowPointer, WINDOW_SHOW_NORMAL);
            checkError("ShowWindow");
            //update window
            bool result = UpdateWindow(windowPointer);
            if(!result) checkError("UpdateWindow");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The message loop.
        /// </summary>
        public void run()
        {
            sbyte code;
            Message message;

            while(true)
            {
                //get the next message
                code = GetMessage(out message, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0);
                //if 0, we're done
                if(code == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }else//if -1, we have error
                if(code == -1)
                {
                    checkError("GetMessage");
                }else
                {
                    //translate
                    TranslateMessage(ref message);
                    //dispatch
                    DispatchMessage(ref message);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Relevant message codes
        /// </summary>
        enum MessageCode : uint
        {
            DESTROY = 0x0002,
            SIZE = 0x0005,
            PAINT = 0x000F,
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Main Message handler.
        /// </summary>
        [AllowReversePInvokeCalls]
        private static IntPtr WindowEvent(IntPtr window, uint message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            switch ((MessageCode)message)
            {
                /*case MessageCode.PAINT:
                    return IntPtr.Zero;
                case MessageCode.SIZE:
                    return IntPtr.Zero;*/
                case MessageCode.DESTROY:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    return IntPtr.Zero;
                default:
                    //pass off to default handling
                    IntPtr result = DefWindowProc(window, message, wParam, lParam);
                    //checkError("DefWindowProc");
                    return result;
            }
        }

        //user32 methods
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern sbyte GetMessage(out Message message, IntPtr window, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool TranslateMessage([In] ref Message message);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr DispatchMessage([In] ref Message message);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern void PostQuitMessage(int exitCode);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr window, uint message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        private static extern ushort RegisterClassEx([In] ref WNDCLASSEX clazz);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx(uint styleEx, uint clazz, string windowName, uint style, int x, int y, int width, int height, IntPtr parent, IntPtr menu, IntPtr hInst, IntPtr param);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr window, int showCommands);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool UpdateWindow(IntPtr window);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadIcon(IntPtr hInst, string iconName);

        //message handler delegate
        private delegate IntPtr EventHandler(IntPtr window, uint message, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        /// <summary>
        /// Message structure
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct Message
        {
            public IntPtr window;
            public uint code;
            public UIntPtr wParam;
            public UIntPtr lParam;
            public uint time;
            public POINT point;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Point structure
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Extended window class structure
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private struct WNDCLASSEX
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int size;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int style;
            public IntPtr wndProc;
            public int clsExtra;
            public int wndExtra;
            public IntPtr hInst;
            public IntPtr icon;
            public IntPtr cursor;
            public IntPtr background;
            public string menuName;
            public string className;
            public IntPtr smIcon;

            public void init(string name, string iconName)
            {
                size = Marshal.SizeOf(this);//set size
                style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;//set style 
                wndProc = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate((Delegate)(EventHandler)WindowEvent);//set the pointer to the message delegate
                clsExtra = 0;//unused
                wndExtra = 0;//unused
                hInst = hInstance;//set hinstance
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(iconName))//if icon not provided, use default
                {
                    icon = SystemIcons.Application.Handle;
                }else//else load given
                {
                    icon = LoadIcon(hInstance, iconName);
                }
                cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default.Handle;//use default cursor
                background = IntPtr.Zero;//use default background
                menuName = null;//no menu
                className = name + "Class";//set class name
                smIcon = IntPtr.Zero;//default small icon
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Execution File:

```
using System;
using UtilLib;

namespace CoreLib
{
    public class Runner
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Window window = new Window("Tester");
            window.run();
        }
    }
}
```

And the console output:

```
RegisterClassEx The system cannot find the file specified 2
CreateWindowEx The system cannot find the file specified 2
ShowWindow Cannot find window class 1407
UpdateWindow Invalid window handle 1400
```

I imagine it is very possible that the code has multiple compounding issues.

Comment: Debug, debug, debug. Find the main problem, and ask it in here if you want. Copy/Pasting your whole code and telling people to find it's problem is so wrong.

Comment: And as the first step to debugging: you are not checking for an error return properly. The mere presence of a `GetLastError()` value is not enough to indicate that an error has occurred, because there is no guarantee that a function succeeding will clear the value. You have to check the return values from each of the functions, only looking for an error if one indicated that it failed. For instance, `RegisterClassEx()` returns zero on failure. Check MSDN for each function's return values.

Comment: And I'm wondering if this is a good design decision, trying to use C# and P/Invoke to create a custom window. I'm thinking it might be better to write a little C++ module to take care of the WinAPI stuff, and then interface with that module from C#.

Comment: clazz.init(title, null); looks wrong  .. in Win32 you cannot initialize a WNDCLASS by a title

Comment: You've got two problems.  It starts with wonky pinvoke declarations that you got from the pinvoke.net web site.  Which is generally not the best place to find good ones, particularly the kind that nobody ever uses.  Like the ones you use.  And your error checking is completely broken.  The combination is pretty fatal of course, you don't stand a chance to get this right.  The .NET Reference Source is a decent place to find good declarations, they get used billions of times each day.  And so are the wrappers that already exist for this, like NativeWindow.

Comment: @MustafaChelik : Did you read the question? Direct quote: "I am fairly certain the problem stems from my definition or instantiation of WNDCLASSEX". The rest of the code was for reference in case that is not the case.

Comment: @andlabs Thank you, I have updated my code accordingly.

Comment: @RenniePet Given my minimal knowledge of C++, I feel that would be opening a whole new can of worms. Maybe I would consider such a task if a good tutorial on the subject existed.

Comment: @LucaRocchi Did you bother to scroll down?

Comment: @HansPassant And the alternative to pinvoke is? I am now aware of my broken error checking, and fixing it atm. Native Window seems to be a good alternative, but I will have to look into it to see if it will work in my specific case.